# Single stepping through C/C++ code with Netbeans 7.1.1 on UBuntu doesn't work

Tags: debugging, netbeans, breakpoints

I am using Netbeans 7.1.1. I have a C++ project that uses stl. I made a clean build on UBuntu (version 10.10-Maverick Meerkat). When I try to single step, the debugger doesn't stop on next line. Instead it continues as if I pressed Continue button.

Is it a known issue?
Am I missing any gotchas?

Thanks
Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Debug->Step Into instead of "Debug Main project" toolbar button for single stepping to work. This is due to Netbeans incompatibility with newer gdb versions (7.2 is what I tried).

One more gotcha I found debugging C++ code from Netbeans is that sometimes it hangs on startup if you are watching some variables. Remove all watch expressions and the debugger works fine.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was struggling with the gdb stuck at some stack frame and doing nothing. After deleting watch expressions, it works again!